# How to stop Filling DataTable ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I didnt found any answer about posibility to stop Filling DataTable. Is there any way to do this? I have data from OleDbDataAdapter and sometime i have to wait 2 min but i want to say to the user to stop filling that amount of data or just just wait and continue.

```
OleDbDataAdapter sqlArchiveData = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql_archive);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

conn.Open();

sqlArchiveData.Fill(dt);

connProdcc1.Close();
```

Comment: No, there's no way to stop it directly. However, you can fill it within another thread and kill the thread on demand, but spinning up your own threads in ASP.NET is dangerous. Instead, you should probably address the underlying issue. *Why* does it take two minutes? Can you optimize the query? Why are you running a process that takes 2 minutes within your website, and not within a background service?

Comment: you could set a low query timeout and catch the exception.

Comment: @dlatikay that wouldn't let the user wait and continue though, once the timeout hits, the execution is finished.

Comment: @Adriano I would use a OleDbDataReader, reading in each record one at a time, checking time elapsed in the loop. If time elapsed > 2 minutes, you can return a message to the user, but keep the data reader open (maybe in the Session["CurrentDataReader"] property. Not ideal, but neither is the architecture you've got here

Comment: true. also it depends on the underlying RDBMS. for example SQL Server would also not support an "abort or continue waiting" approach except after the first record is returned, and mostly that will be the bottleneck, not the transmission of the records once they're fetched, unless the dataset is very large.

Comment: You could combine a `CancellationToken` with an `OleDbDataReader`. The data reader is a stream that reads data in chunks instead of one big operation like `Fill()`.

Comment: I cannot optimize my query because it's not a problem here. The problem that takes a lot of time is Fill() a DataTable. I have a base with couple of milion records and when a user take some parameters that will try to fill a milion of records to DataTable it will take a lot of time. So i think the best way here it's meaby throw a Exception or use OleDbDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can handle canceling the fill in the [DataTable RowChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) by passing a `CancellationToken`. The following example spins up a [Backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) which isn't optimal in ASP.NET, but should give you some ideas.

Example taken from the following MSDN forum post.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad4f5811-a08d-4342-bcf1-368ceac834fc/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-a-dataadapterfill-command-while-its-processing?forum=csharpgeneral

```
private BackgroundWorker worker;
private DataTable table;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (worker != null)
  {
    worker.CancelAsync();
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
  worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

  worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
  worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

  worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(this.table.Rows.Count.ToString());
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  this.table = new DataTable();

  using (SqlConnection connection= new SqlConnection())
  using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table", connection))
  {
    table.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(table_RowChanged); 
    da.Fill(table);        
  }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
void table_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
  if (worker.CancellationPending)
  {
    throw new ApplicationException("Canceled"); // throw a spanner in the works
  }
  Thread.Sleep(5); // Just slow things down for testing
}
```

Comment: i try to do this, but when i just add button which i can call out other event it just stop me executing a Filling

Comment: @Adriano This is just an example. The point I was trying to make is you can pass a cancellation token to the Row_Changed event to stop filling.

Comment: Yes i understand your point but i think im not good enough to use that well. Thanks anyway